# Search in a sheet for a query while cell equals specific value (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a code to search for a query in a column, while holding certain value in another column.

example : as long as any cell in column A = 100 , Then search for "Text 1" in column B

When this 100 becomes 200 then search for "Text 2" in column B.. and so on till the last row of the sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Sub SearchQuery()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Sheets("New Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Criteria search
        If Sheets("New Sheet").Cells(i, 1).Value = "40042710" Then
            If Sheets("New Sheet").Cells(i, 2).Value = "11:35:00 AM" Then
                  'Set the Cell value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Need a few more details to provide good answer to this:
- Could you find the target value in a given column more than once and if so, would you keep looking for others or stop there?
- Is your data range continuous or are you likely to have breaks (empty cells) in your column?
- You have lots of data? Because writing/reading like this can be slow.... If so you may have have to use arrays

Comment: Thanks for your attention, yes the given value can be repeated like 5 or 6 times (afterwards), then the next set of rows will hold a new value which will be repeated Also 5 or 6 times, and so on.... there is no empty cells. i have around 500 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are only two directly linked values, the `Scripting.Dictionary` object can prove quite useful. The `dictionary.Exists(key)` function makes it simple to test for valid keys. The similar `Scripting.Collection` object lacks this functionality.

Here's a rough snippet showcasing how you might use it. Note that you'll need to set a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* or use *late binding* instead!

```
Sub Example()
    Dim keyRange As Range
    Dim valueRange As Range
    Dim keyCell As Range
    Dim valueCell As Range
    Dim searchKey As String
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim noDuplicateSearches As Boolean: noDuplicateSearches = True
    Dim criteria As New Dictionary

    With criteria ' criteria as key-value pairs
        .Add "100", "Text 1"
        .Add "200", "Text 2"
    End With

    Set keyRange = Sheets(1).Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set valueRange = Sheets(1).Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    For Each keyCell In keyRange
        searchKey = keyCell.Value

        If criteria.Exists(searchKey) Then ' on a valid key
            searchValue = criteria(searchKey)

            For Each valueCell In valueRange
                If valueCell.Value = searchValue Then ' on a valid value
                    Debug.Print "Found", searchValue, _
                                "using", searchKey, _
                                "at", valueCell.Address
                End If
            Next valueCell

            If noDuplicateSearches Then criteria.Remove searchKey
        End If
    Next keyCell

End Sub
```

---

Of course, generating the entire `criteria` dictionary each time the sub is run is far from optimal. You could choose to use a different sub to initialize (or unload!) the dictionary in a public variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that you know exactly what values your search depends upon.  I would search the column using something like the below link:

[How to find a value in an excel column by vba code Cells.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14931700/5692872)

Then I would follow that up with a Select Case to search again for whatever you desire.

The following link is to the MSDN Select Case page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Example: search column A for value 100. if exists then set the Cells.Find() parameters accordingly. If the value 100 is not found in column A then search for 200, etc.