# Compare data in two sheets and highlight differences in mismatches

Tags: excel, vba, compare, macro-recorder

I have checked answers given in other questions, but since I am a newcomer to excel vba macros, I really can't find a way to get my problem solved using solutions provided.

**EDIT: I am not able to write code on my own yet. I started one month ago with macros, copying and pasting from different posts, and editing as I needed, with many errors usually that I need to fix. It's pretty frustrating but I see this just too big of a problem to get it done on my own.**

Thanks in advance for your kind help and shared knowledge.

I have two excel sheets that:

1. Contain different columns, of which I need to check three of them for matching values
2. Number of entries (rows) in both may differ (different lenght)
3. Values may or may not be sorted
4. For every value in row A, macro shall check value in row B and C, and compare against sheet2, and the same routine taking as reference values in sheet 2 against sheet 1.
5. Row A is numerical, B is numerical, and C is text

Example:

**Sheet 1**

```
    A         B            C        D        E  
1  Code     Revision     Status  
2  102        0            C  
3  102        1            A  
4   89        0            A  
5  216        0            C  
6  216        1            B  
7  216        2            A  
8  217        0            B
```

**Sheet 2**

```
    A         B            C        D        E
1  Code     Revision     Status  
2  102        0            A  
3  102        1            A  
4   89        0            A  
5   90        0            A  
6  216        0            C  
7  216        1            B  
8  216        2            A  
9   16        0            A
```

After the macro runs, the result in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 should be that:

1. All values in column A in Sheet 2 that are missing in Sheet 1 shall be colored its background in, say, red.
2. All values in column A in Sheet 1 that are missing in Sheet 2 shall be colored its background in, say, red.
3. The same way, for values in column A that are matching in both sheets, missing 'Revisions' (Column B) in each sheet shall be highlighted the same way as in previous points 1 and 2
4. finally, for rows that match both 'Code' and 'Revision' (Column A and B) in both sheets, in case that the 'Status' (Column C) is not matching, highlight in Sheet 1.

The result would color red the following cells:

Sheet 1:

- C2
- A8

Sheet 2:

- A5
- A9

Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? please show us what you've tried and what your *specific programming problem* is.

Comment: Excel VBA macros have nothing to do with Google spreadsheets. Choose tags appropriately.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change anything.  Break the process up into smaller pieces, get each one to work one at a time, and then eventually you will have a complete procedure that does everything.  If you run into a specific problem with the code, feel free to post it here and I'm sure someone will help.  If you want to learn how to code in VBA, keep plugging away and trying.  The people here have many years of experience with this, which is why they know how to do things so quickly.  They are glad to help, but we have our own jobs and are not being paid to do yours.

Comment: Ok, I will try. This is not actually my job, but I wanted this code to check sheets that I use for work to compare possible mistakes. I will post back when I can get something any close to the code I'm looking for.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but in fact that is your job; you are trying to automate and improve it, which is laudable.  Anything you learn will be quite useful in future endeavors, and the hard work will be worth it.  If anyone were to give you the code, you wouldn't learn anything [or at least much].  When/if you do run into issues, make a new question as this one probably will not be seen at that point.

Comment: @OpiesDad I have done something close to what I was looking for. I hope this is what you were mentioning. Anyhow, I am not sure this is the proper way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could manage to prepare this code that more or less does what I wanted, with some modifications to speed up the testing:

It checks sets of lists (3 columns) in two sheets, and verifies whether all conditions stated previously in this post match.

If matching occurs, it adds a new value in column E, with value 'Ok'.

This, combined to conditional formatting in the excel sheets, highlights rows that are found matching values en A, B and C.

**The code seems to work and some improvements may be taken, but since I have to process some thousands of rows, I am afraid is gonna take too long.**

Is there a more eficient way to do so, rather than looping through all the rows?

This is the code:

```
Sub Compare()

' Declare all the variables needed
  Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngName As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer

Dim varCode1 As Integer
Dim varRevision1 As Integer
Dim varStatus1 As String

Dim varCode2 As Integer
Dim varRevision2 As Integer
Dim varStatus2 As String

' Process second sheet
 For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)
    varCode2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
    varRevision2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value
    varStatus2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value
    ' MsgBox "Code " & varCode2 & ", Rev. " & varRevision2 & ", Status " & varStatus2
    For j = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j)
        If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
        varCode1 = rng2.Copy
        varRevision1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Value
        varStatus1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value
        ' This will just write 'Ok' in cells with matches between column A and B

        If varRevision1 = varRevision2 And varStatus1 = varStatus2 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Value = "Ok"
        End If

        End If

        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
Next i

' Process first sheet
For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
    varCode1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    varRevision1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
    varStatus1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value
    ' MsgBox "Code " & varCode2 & ", Rev. " & varRevision2 & ", Status " & varStatus2
    For j = 2 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j)
        If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
        varCode2 = rng2.Copy
        varRevision2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & j).Value
        varStatus2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & j).Value
        ' This will just write 'Ok' in cells with matches between column A and B

        If varRevision2 = varRevision1 And varStatus2 = varStatus1 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value = "Ok"
        End If

        End If

        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: If you have another question, you should make a question, not post an answer with another question.  With that said, consider using the method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931700/how-to-find-a-value-in-an-excel-column-by-vba-code-cells-find to find the value instead of looping.  Also, if your code is working, your question should go on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I applaud you for your attitude and effort.  A lot of people just give up when you give them feedback to try to figure it out themselves first.  And you did figure out a solution...Kudos.

Comment: Thanks. It's true that you learn a lot more from trying yourself.