# Search row for clipboard value, when value found, filter column with cliboard value

Tags: excel, vba, search, filter, rows

Bit of a novice, but I've gotten as far as I think I can without assistance:

I'm trying to create a macro to do the following:

1) Search a column (B) for user inputted value

2) When value in (1) found, copy contents of cell in column U of active row

3) Search rest of row after column U for value copied in (2)

4) If value copied in (2) is found again (only at the 1st repetition after column U) in the row, filter column of cell it was found in with the same value

It looks like I have steps 1 & 2 working, not sure if step 3 doesn't work or is failing because the loop starts from column A and stops when it comes across the clipboard value in column U (rather than searching beyond column U). Step 4 looks to be definitely not working.

Thanks for any and all assistance in resolving steps 3&4.

Using the example below, if the user inputs 9 in MyFind/Input box, then column B would be searched to find 9 in cell B2 (Values in column B will always be unique). The rest of row 2 (after column B) will be searched to find 9 repeated in cell E2. Column E is then filtered with 9 as the criteria.

..A BC DE F G

1|1 2 3 4 5 6 7

2|1 9 3 4 9 9 7

3|1 8 3 4 9 6 7

4|1 3 3 4 5 6 7

My Code:

```
Sub LCOUN_Search()
Dim OrgNum As Integer
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


MyFind = InputBox("Please enter 8 digit employee number:") 
    If MyFind = "" Then End

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
   If Range("B" & i).Value = MyFind Then
      Range("B" & i).Select
   End If
Next i

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "U").Select
Selection.Copy

LastCol = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "V").End(xlToLeft).Column  
*'?Column V so that it searches from after column U?*

For i = LastCol To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i) = Selection Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.Copy

        End If
Next i

Columns(ActiveCell.Column).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=Selection

End Sub
```

I've also tried this:

```
Sub LCOUN_Search()

Dim Found As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


MyFind = InputBox("Please enter 8 digit employee number:")
    If MyFind = "" Then End

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
   If Range("B" & i).Value = MyFind Then
      Range("B" & i).Select
   End If
Next i


Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "U").Select
Found = Selection.Copy

FirstCol = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "V").Column      
LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column + _
                ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1


For k = FirstCol To LastCol
    If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, k) = Selection Then Exit For 
Next k

If k <= LastCol Then                             
     With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
          .AutoFilter Field:=k, Criteria1:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, k).contents
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at using .Find on Range(“B1:B” & lastRow). Sorry about funny “” due to mobile. That, if found, will return the address where found, then take that value and repeat the .Find on the row on the range U same row to last column U row. I am not sure what you mean by the first repetition. You can also specify search order with .Find.

Comment: You will also need error handling for no user input or user pressed cancel and if no match found by .Find. May also be worth restricting InputBox type argument to restrict data type expected from user input and add some basic validation checking user input is a valid Id.

Comment: The copied value is likely to be repeated a few times in the row (after column U, e.g. In columns BA, BB, BC) by first repetition I mean the first time after column U that the value is repeated  (e.g. Column BA)

Comment: .Find can be used to return the first if you specify the order by columns. Tbh, if you narrow the search  range to 1 row I am not sure if search order even matters but something to investigate. Worth looking at the MSDN documentation on it. It will be a lot more efficient than the method you are trying at present.

Comment: Still can't get it working, I've tried the 2nd code in my edited question above as well s using .Find instead of a loop

Comment: I can’t see you using the  Find function https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you search in a wrong direction: you start in column "V" and come BACK to column A.)

If you want to filter on column "B" then you should apply `Field:=2`.

Try this:

```
FirstCol = Cells(i, "V").Column      ' employee is found in row i
LastCol = Activesheet.Usedrange.Column + _  
                Activesheet.Usedrange.Columns.Count - 1

For k = FirstCol to LastCol
    If Cells(i, k) = MyFind Then Exit For ' break the loop when found
Next k

If k <= LastCol Then                              ' found
     With Activesheet.Usedrange
          .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=MyFind    ' column B
          .AutoFilter Field:=k, Criteria1:=MyFind
     End With
End If
```

You can opt for using .Find, then you can search the rest of the row for the value, so the command is:

```
Dim rFound As Range
Set rFound = Range(Cells(i, FirstCol), CElls(i, LastCol)).Find(What:=MyFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rFound Is Nothing then       ' found (1st match after U)
     ' here rFound.Column gives you the column of found cell
```

EDITED answer due to altered requirements: for searching one row from column C to column U change 1st and last column like this and it will do what you need.

```
FirstCol = 3           ' C
LastCol = Cells(i, "U").Column  ' it's not easy to memorize which column is U
```

Comment: Maybe fully qualify ranges

Comment: @QHarr, I agree, and avoid using Activesheet and Activecell and Selection etc but that's gonna be the topic of the next training :)

Comment: Thank you for the responses, however I'm still having trouble

Comment: I've edited my question to provide a little more detail

Answer (score 0):

This could be tidied up but shows you an example with `Find` function

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub LCOUN_Search()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")             'change as appropriate
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim myFind As String

ResumeLine:
    On Error Resume Next
    myFind = InputBox("Please enter 8 digit employee number or press Cancel to quit.") 'tested with user input 12345686
    On Error GoTo 0

    If myFind = vbNullString Then
        End
    ElseIf Len(myFind) < 8 Or Len(myFind) > 8 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter an 8 digit employee number"
        GoTo ResumeLine
    End If

    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim initialSearchRange As Range
    Set initialSearchRange = ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

    With initialSearchRange

        Set foundCell = .Find(myFind, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

            Dim foundRow As Long
            foundRow = foundCell.Row
            Set foundCell = Nothing

            Dim lastColumn As Long
            lastColumn = ws.Cells(foundRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            myFind = ws.Range("U" & foundRow)

            If myFind = vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "Value not found after column U"
                End
            End If

            Dim newSearchRange As Range
            Set newSearchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(foundRow, "V"), ws.Cells(foundRow, lastColumn))

            Set foundCell = newSearchRange.Find(myFind, LookIn:=xlValues)

            Dim filterValue As String

            If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

                filterValue = CStr(foundCell)    'this depends on what datatype you are expecting to have returned
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, "A"), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=foundCell.Column, Criteria1:=filterValue

            End If

        End If

    End With


End Sub
```

References:

1) [How to find a value in an excel column by vba code Cells.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931700/how-to-find-a-value-in-an-excel-column-by-vba-code-cells-find)

2) [Find last row, column or last cell](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Example filter below (Apologies but usual method of pasting in image for SO doesn't seem to be working so getting a lot of white space with image):

[image: Example filter]

Note in the above there are not proper headers. Your example didn't mention this. If there are headers bear in mind when setting ranges you may need to use either row = 1 or row = 2 rather than just row = 1 as in the code provided. The principle here was the use of Find to fulfil the steps you described.