# How To Find A Specific Cell With The Relevent Data?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find some macro that will run all over the worksheet and select all the relevant cells.

I have written some macro that find the cell but only one cell-its not selecting all the cells.

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Range("A1:GG1000")
Dim mynumer As Integer
mynumber = 7
For Each myCell In myRange
If myCell = mynumber Then

myCell.Select


End If
Next myCell
```

how i can run the macro and see all the relevant cells?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try some [`.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) iteration.

Just adapted from the above link:

```
Sub Test()

Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:GG1000")
    Set cl = .Find(7, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
     If Not cl Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = cl.Address
        Do
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Union(rng, cl)
            Else
                Set rng = cl
            End If
            Debug.Print rng.Address
            Set cl = .FindNext(cl)
        If cl Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DF
        End If
        Loop While cl.Address <> firstAddress
      End If
DF:
    rng.Select
End With

End Sub
```

The question really is, why do you `.Select` a range? Most of the time that can be avoided, and most likely the code above can be amended to something much cleaner!

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at this answer:
[How to find a value in an excel column by vba code Cells.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931700/how-to-find-a-value-in-an-excel-column-by-vba-code-cells-find#14931758)

The answer beneath the top voted, shows you how to search in the whole spreadsheet.

Best regards,

Timo

Comment: You should quote the answer and provide a Link. As link may stop working anytime.