# Find function to locate result of a formula, in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to look into column F and find number 9999 to return the cell reference.

My code returns the cell where this number is located only if the number 9999 is typed into column F.

Column F is formula driven and the number 9999 is the outcome of the logic behind the formula.

```vb
Dim foundRng as Range
Set foundRng = Range ("F1:F2000").Find("9999")
If foundRng is Nothing then
    MsgBox "Value not found"
Else
    MsgBox foundrng.Address
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931700/how-to-find-a-value-in-an-excel-column-by-vba-code-cells-find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a value in an excel column by vba code Cells.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931700/how-to-find-a-value-in-an-excel-column-by-vba-code-cells-find)

Answer (score 1):

The `Find` function has many properties. Most of them are set by Excel automatically, depending upon last use. Even if you last used `Find` manually, Excel will remember your last setting. Therefore you should set all relevant properties when using VBA.

```
Sub FindCell()

    Dim foundRng As Range
    
    Set foundRng = Range("F1:F2000").Find(What:="9999", _
                                          After:=Cells(2000, "F"), _
                                          LookIn:=vbValues, _
                                          LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                          MatchCase:=False)
    If foundRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value not found"
    Else
        MsgBox foundRng.Address
    End If
```

The likely source of your problem is the `LookIn` property which I suspect your system currently uses `xlFormulas` (it's `xlValues`above). When a cell has a hard value, like `9999`, its formula and value are the same. But if the formla is `=3*3333` value and formula differ and 9999 will not be found in the formula.

The other item worth mentioning is the `After` property. Excel starts the search in the cell ***after*** the specified cell (by default the first cell in the range). The next cell *after* is specified by the `SearchDirection` property (above `xlNext`, could be `xlPrevious`). The function will loop through the entire range. Therefore, by specifying the last cell as *after* and `xlNext` as direction, the search will actually start in the first cell whereas, if the first cell is specified as `After` it will, in fact, be the last cell to be examined.