# VBA Find function "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

When I try using the following code to find the address of specific cells in one workbook, and copy the address to another wb it works fine.

```
        Set ra_from = wb_from.Sheets("Core").Cells.Find(What:=cel_name, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        wb_macro.Sheets("Engine").Activate
        wb_macro.Sheets("Engine").Range(cel.Address).Offset(0, 3) = ra_from.Addres
```

However, I would like to search only in one column, so I switched Cells for Columns("B:B")

```
        Set ra_from = wb_from.Sheets("Core").Columns("B:B").Find(What:=cel_name, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        wb_macro.Sheets("Engine").Activate
        wb_macro.Sheets("Engine").Range(cel.Address).Offset(0, 3) = ra_from.Address
```

And I get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set". Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: What is `cel`?  Is this defined or set somewhere?

Comment: `Set ra_from = wb_from.Sheets("Core").Columns("B:B").Cells.Find(W...`  You forgot `.Cells.`

Comment: Hi, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931700/how-to-find-a-value-in-an-excel-column-by-vba-code-cells-find) to your question is here :).

Comment: Cel is a Range (it is a cell). @ron unfortunately still getting the same error

Comment: This only means that no match has been found for `cel_name` in the searched column. When stopped on error, please move the mouse over `ra_from`. Doesn't it show `Nothing`?

Comment: Try adding `, After:=wb_from.Sheets("Core").Range("B1")`. And no need of `wb_macro.Sheets("Engine").Activate`

Comment: Then it didn't find a match.

Comment: Was pointing to the wrong column. Thanks Ron!